# How should the TaskScheduler COM object be disposed once we're done with it?

Tags: .net, com, com-interop

It seems like the `TaskScheduler.TaskScheduler` type from the 'TaskScheduler' COM type library (v1.1) does not actually implement `IDisposable`. Should we call `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` on it instead, or what?

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7467632/why-dont-com-object-use-idisposable

Comment: I looked at it once, they didn't make it easy to do the simple thing.  Very broad object model, but the objects themselves are probably very small.  You can try ReleaseComObject but I seriously doubt you'll notice, either because you forgot one or very little memory gets released.  Just do nothing, the garbage collector takes care of it.  If it does matter then [just help it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25135685/17034).