# C# interface to COM leaks memory... strangely

Tags: c#, com, memory-leaks

I have a C# program that accesses a COM Interface to a piece of simulation software called Aspen Plus.  I have a very strange memory leak.

When I need to get the result values out of the simulation, I run a series of calls like this, in some cases the variable returned might be null, so I insert a check for that.  Then I use FinalReleaseComObject to clean up the COM references.

```
   public override ValueType recvValueFromSim<ValueType>(string path) {
       Happ.IHNode tree = this.Aspen.Tree;
       dynamic node = tree.FindNode(path);
       ValueType retVal = default(ValueType);
       if (node != null && node.Value != null) {
           retVal = node.Value;
       }
       Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(node);
       Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(tree);
       node = null;
       return retVal;
   }
```

Unfortunately, the above code leaks a lot.  It leaks 2MB per simulation.  At first I thought the Garbage Collector would eventually run and clean it up, but no dice.  After running a couple of hundred simulations, I ran out of memory.

The bizarre thing is, the below code works fine and doesn't leak. I didn't like it, because using catch to check for null references seems like bad form, but this doesn't leak.

```
   public override ValueType recvValueFromSim<ValueType>(string path) {
      ValueType node;
      try {
         node = this.Aspen.Tree.FindNode(path).Value;
         return node;
      } catch {
         return default(ValueType);
      }
   }
```

Why doesn't it leak?  Does anybody know?  The belies why I thought I knew about temporary references and releasing COM objects.

Comment: I'll potentially step on toes to suggest that in C# using a catch to trap a null-ref is **correct** form, albeit odd at first for C/C++ aficionados.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937181/when-to-use-releasecomobject-vs-finalreleasecomobject

Comment: can you say to us result of the `FinalReleaseComObject` method call?

Comment: Originally I didn't have the ReleaseComObject calls at all, but it leaked.  They didn't help the leak, but I left them here so I wouldn't get a bunch of suggestions to add them.

Comment: FInalReleaseComObject always returns 0, so it seems to be successful.