# Method System.Runtime.InteopServices.Marshal.ReleaseCOMObject doesn't kill all object

Tags: .net, com, com-interop

Why a dll registered into COM+ components has "Activated Count" equal 1 even if the caller process(.net 2.0 Assembly) always use the method `System.Runtime.InteopServices.Marshal.ReleaseCOMObject()` ?

ReleaseCOMObject really disactivate object if the counter is greater of 1 but remain always one object active until timeout expired.

Comment: pretty sure com ref counts have to be 0 before you release them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very similar to another question on SO

> [Why use FinalReleaseComObject instead of ReleaseComObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827059/why-use-finalreleasecomobject-instead-of-releasecomobject)

Generally the remaining refcount indicates that there is another managed object holding onto a reference that has not yet been garbage-collected.  (Usually the RCW)