# How to close excel in C#?

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to run Excel macro and close excel after run.
Unfortunately it does not work. I tried all solutions from Stackoverflow and could not get reliable solution. Please help.
As you can see I am trying to close, quite, release COM object but nothing seems to be working.

```
public static bool RunMacro(string Path, string MacroName, bool Close, ProgressForm ProgressForm, params object[] Arguments)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application aApplication = null;
    bool aCloseApplication = true;
    bool aResult = false;

    try
    {
        aApplication = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
        aCloseApplication = false;
    }
    catch (COMException aCOMException)
    {
        aApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        aApplication.Visible = false;
    }

    if (aApplication != null)
    {
        aApplication.ScreenUpdating = false;

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook aWorkbook = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet aWorksheet = null;
        bool aCloseWorkbook = true;

        try
        {
            if (IsEdited(aApplication))
            {
                throw new Exception("Excel is in cell edit mode. Please stop editing cell and run import again");
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < aApplication.Workbooks.Count; i++)
                    if (aApplication.Workbooks[i + 1].FullName == Path)
                    {
                        aWorkbook = aApplication.Workbooks[i + 1];
                        aCloseWorkbook = false;
                        break;
                    }

                if (aWorkbook == null)
                    aWorkbook = aApplication.Workbooks.Open(Path);

                // Run macro here
                aApplication.Run(string.Format("{0}!{1}", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Path), MacroName), Arguments);

                aResult = true;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (aWorksheet != null)
            {
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(aWorksheet);
            }

            //does not work here!!! I want to close excel here 
            if (aWorkbook != null)
                aWorkbook.Close();
                aApplication.Quit();
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(aWorkbook);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(aApplication);
        }
    }
    return aResult;
}
```

Comment: `aApplication.Workbooks.Count` - https://ausdotnet.wordpress.com/2008/05/26/com-interop-principle-2-fear-the-period/

Comment: `aApplication.Workbooks[i + 1];` - https://ausdotnet.wordpress.com/2008/06/04/com-interop-principle-3-fear-the-hidden-period/

Comment: simply look for the process "Excel" and kill it?

Comment: @mjwills thanks, It is so many comments and I am testing them all right now so far nothing works I want solution that will make this script working. I will review links and hope to find something useful.

Comment: @FakeCaleb I do not want to kill if possible but find elegant solution to close excel if possible. Kill will be my last option I guess

Comment: You missed one.  Not being able to debug this is why you should never write this kind of code.  All it takes is for the garbage collector to run, it never misses anything.  So keep doing useful things and it will run.  If it has to quit when you say so then it takes GC.Collect().  It must be called in the code that calls this method if it also needs to work when you debug.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Application not quitting after calling quit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697282/application-not-quitting-after-calling-quit)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37904483/as-of-today-what-is-the-right-way-to-work-with-com-objects may also be of assistance. _I do not recommend this approach for Excel specifically. The main issue with using GC.Collect is it is a global solution to a local problem. It may solve the issue for your Excel objects, but it will force a GC across everything - thus increasing the rate of mid-life crisis._ https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ricom/2003/12/04/mid-life-crisis.

Comment: @mijwilla it is `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();` step that close excel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is something I've played around with a lot while using SSIS Script Tasks to refresh Excel files.

I've read mixed things about using `Marshal.ReleaseComObject`, but I've also found that it isn't necessary. For me, the ultimate solution was found to be the following:

```
using xl = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

...

public void Main()
{
    DoExcelWork();

    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
}

private void DoExcelWork()
{
    xl.Application app = null;
    xl.Workbooks books = null;
    xl.Workbook book = null;

    try
    {
        app = new xl.Application() { DisplayAlerts = false };

        books = app.Workbooks;
        book = books.Open("file path goes here");

        book.RefreshAll();
        // this is where you would do your Excel work

        app.DisplayAlerts = false; // This is for reinforcement; the setting has been known to reset itself after a period of time has passed.
        book.SaveAs("save path goes here");
        app.DisplayAlerts = true;

        book.Close();
        app.Quit();
    }
    catch
    {
        if (book != null) book.Close(SaveChanges: false);
        if (app != null) app.Quit();
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how your application is laid out, but when using SSIS I found it was necessary to call `GC.Collect` outside of the scope where the Excel Interop objects were declared in order to avoid having the Excel instances left open on some occasions, hence the two methods.

You should be able to adapt this code to suit your requirements.

Comment: it is step `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();` that close EXCEL thanks @Chris

Comment: Well, `GC.Collect()` is what initiates/forces the disposal, and `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()` waits until the disposal is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Three things:

- Close Excel, either manually or programmatically. Excel might popup a question box asking if you would like to save (even if Excel is currently hidden). It has to actually get closed for this to work; if you choose cancel it won't have been closed. There should be an overload that allows you to ignore unsaved changes.
- Set the reference to `null`.
- Call `GC.Collect();`.

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.quit.aspx) one way to prevent a box from blocking the close attempt is to set [DisplayAlerts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.displayalerts.aspx) to `false`. (Though you would lose changes.)

As far as I know the `Marshall` stuff you're doing is unnecessary (according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37904483/as-of-today-what-is-the-right-way-to-work-with-com-objects), it's in fact dangerous). What I specifically do is wrap the interop object in my own `Excel` object which implements `IDisposable`. My `Dispose` method looks basically like this (though I do some other things too, like always `Show` Excel if it wasn't closed, always turn back on rendering and auto-calculation, etc.)

```
void Dispose() {
   if (mExcel != null) {
      mExcel = null;
      GC.Collect();
   }
}
```

And have static methods which implement the correct usage pattern:

```
public static void UseAndClose(Action<Excel> pAction) {
   using (var excel = new Excel()) {
      pAction(excel);
      excel.Close(false); // closes all workbooks and then calls `Quit`
   }
}
```

Comment: you mean at the end, after if: `aWorkbook = null` and `GC.Collect()` after `Marshal.ReleaseComObject(aApplication);` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you do decide to use the `Marshal.ReleaseCOMObject` technique (as opposed to `GC.Collect`) then the key is to ensure you are releasing **every single RCW (COM Object)**, not just *some* of them.

An example, based on your original code:

```
public static bool RunMacro(string Path, string MacroName, bool Close, params object[] Arguments)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application aApplication = null;
    bool aCloseApplication = true;
    bool aResult = false;

    try
    {
        aApplication = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
        aCloseApplication = false;
    }
    catch (COMException aCOMException)
    {
        aApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        aApplication.Visible = false;
    }

    if (aApplication != null)
    {
        aApplication.ScreenUpdating = false;

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook aWorkbook = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet aWorksheet = null;
        bool aCloseWorkbook = true;

        try
        {
            if (IsEdited(aApplication))
            {
                throw new Exception("Excel is in cell edit mode. Please stop editing cell and run import again");
            }
            else
            {
                var workbooks = aApplication.Workbooks;
                for (int i = 0; i < workbooks.Count; i++)
                {
                    var workbook = aApplication.Workbooks.Item[i + 1];
                    if (workbook.FullName == Path)
                    {
                        aWorkbook = workbook;
                        aCloseWorkbook = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook);
                    }
                }

                if (aWorkbook == null)
                    aWorkbook = workbooks.Open(Path);

                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbooks);

                // Run macro here
                aApplication.Run(string.Format("{0}!{1}", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Path), MacroName),
                    Arguments);

                aResult = true;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (aWorksheet != null)
            {
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(aWorksheet);
            }

            //does not work here!!! I want to close excel here 
            if (aWorkbook != null)
                aWorkbook.Close();
            aApplication.Quit();
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(aWorkbook);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(aApplication);
        }
    }
    return aResult;
}
```

Note that I have introduced some extra variables. `workbooks` and `workbook` to point to objects that were not `RCO`ing in your original code.

In terms of deciding between this technique (using `ReleaseCOMObject`) and the other technique (using `GC.Collect`) there are a number of factors to consider:

- `ReleaseCOMObject` requires more discipline (to ensure that you release everything, consider the [double dot rule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17367570/34092), realise that `application.Workbooks["something]"` is actually shorthand for `application.Workbooks.Item["something"]` (and thus has [two dots](https://ausdotnet.wordpress.com/2008/06/04/com-interop-principle-3-fear-the-hidden-period/)) etc etc)
- `ReleaseCOMObject` is particularly hard if the lifetime of the object involved is hard to track in your code (not the case in your code, since the lifetime you want is basically the function scope - but it can apply in some scenarios). As [Chris Brumme](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cbrumme/2003/04/16/releasecomobject/) states :

  > If you are a client application using a modest number of COM objects
  >   that are passed around freely in your managed code, you should not use
  >   ReleaseComObject.
- `GC.Collect()` is simpler (basically just call `GC.Collect();` and `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();` until `Marshal.AreComObjectsAvailableForCleanup()` returns `false`).
- `GC.Collect` is generally slower (since it needs to GC **everything** not just the [RCWs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/runtime-callable-wrapper) involved).
- `GC.Collect` (well, more specifically `Marshal.AreComObjectsAvailableForCleanup`) can be problematic if multiple threads are involved (since it may return `true` due to other RCWs (from other threads), not just the ones you are specifically interested in in this scope).
- `GC.Collect` may reduce your overall system performance since it may contribute to [mid life crisis](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ricom/2003/12/04/mid-life-crisis) for all of your objects (by pushing them into a later GC generation than they would have been in otherwise).

*Note that if you do decide to use the `GC.Collect`, the other answers here are excellent in giving some guidance as to how to go about doing that.*

Answer (score -1):

You should never ever call `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` and `Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject` methods within `Excel Interop`; it's a bad practice.

No one (including `Microsoft`) explicitly indicates that you have to release `COM` references manually since your application and the interop library are supposed to handle this automatically. And even if you want to keep on releasing `COM` references manually, once it's done you have to ensure that they are cleaned up when the process ends by calling `GC.Collect()` and `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()` (on a side note, the `GC` may fail if you run the method from the debugger since local references are kepy alive until the end of a method).

This is all you have to do:

```
// let's make sure that the process doesn't hang because of alerts
aApplication.DisplayAlerts = false;

aWorkbook.Save();
aWorkbook.Close();

aApplication.Quit()
aApplication = null;
```

Comment: I tested this solution just now and it did not worked. Sorry

Comment: This works but you have to set the application reference to `null`, or `GC.Collect` will not collect the object.

Comment: @DaveCousineau `This works but you have to set the application reference to null` That may not _always_ be true -  https://blog.stephencleary.com/2010/02/q-should-i-set-variables-to-null-to.html

Comment: @mjwills yes, I think if it goes out of scope that is good enough, too (like if it's a local variable or something). but otherwise, I haven't tested it in a while, but if I recall it's easy to demonstrate that the excel.exe does disappear if you set the reference to null, and doesn't if you don't.

Comment: When debugging it can definitely _look_ like you need to leave function scope or need to set it to null @DaveCousineau . See `When the JIT Compiler Behaves Differently (Debug)` in https://blog.stephencleary.com/2010/02/q-should-i-set-variables-to-null-to.html .